# Convenient number of hands played on a Omaha table of 6 players

Tags: pre-flop, omaha

I play Omaha for fun, but well allbody wants to win.

I realized, after reading "The big play strategy", I had a high percentage of hands played: ~40% playing in 6 players tables.

I have been trying to reduce the numbers of hands I play to 30%, wich lead to a bit more boring experience while playing, but better results.

I wonder if I am still playing too many hands.

What percentage of hands should be played at a six players Omaha table?